# Optimization and MLE in J programming language

Tags: j

I am currently working on a statistical problem that requires optimization, specifically MLE (maximum likelihood estimation), as described here:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_likelihood_estimation

I am running into some basic problems, however, and am wondering if there are any pointers someone can give me to basic optimization functions in J. For instance, in R, there is a library called "stats4" that contains functions like this:

https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats4/html/mle.html

I would be happy to rewrite this in J, but might want to have some of the statistical building blocks if they're available. Am I missing anything, or are there optimization helper functions in J anywhere?

Answer (score 1):

Probably the best place to begin is the stats library which has `/base` `/distribs` `/r` `/rlibrary` folders. It can be accessed via the Package Manager in the Tools menu of the J ide.

stats/base has these scripts

```
base.ijs
combinatorial.ijs
distribution.ijs
multivariate.ijs
random.ijs
sampledesign.ijs
univariate.ijs
```

stats/distribs has these scripts

```
distribs.ijs
normal.ijs
uniform.ijs
test_normal.ijs
test_uniform.ijs
```

stats/r has these scripts

```
rbase.ijs
rdcmd.ijs
rdsock.ijs
rserve.ijs
rserver.ijs
test_rbase.ijs
test_rserve.ijs
test_rserver.ijs
```

stats/rlibrary has these files

```
splines.ijs
test_splines.ijs
```

These may be a good place to start as the scripts may illustrate best practices if not the applications that you are looking for.

J is already pretty optimized (especially the 806 beta) but may not have all of the functions that you are looking for. If you write your own, pay attention to special code when writing performance critical functions. A good reference is located here: http://code.jsoftware.com/wiki/Vocabulary/SpecialCombinations